# How to query only documents from a library filtering out folders

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, flow, power-automate, file

I need to get all documents from a lib. I use Get files (properties only). It returns documents and folders as well as separate items.

How I can set a query to return only documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure your Get files (properties only) like below:

[image]

Use below in **Filter Query**:

```
FSObjType eq 0
```

It will return only the documents from document library.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much